# Remote Maria Database working in HeideSQL/DBeaver but not in Java application or DataGrip

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb, timeout

I'm having a problem with this database I'm working with. When I run my application, I get this:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=mydomain.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : Read timed out
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:192)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1392)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at com.myapplication.db.Database.getConnection(Database.java:15)
    at com.myapplication.controllers.auth.SignInController.lambda$checkIfAdminExists$5(SignInController.java:69)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Read timed out
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Read timed out

    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2076)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1527)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1506)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1031)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:880)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:595)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1387)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:981)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.ReadAheadBufferedStream.fillBuffer(ReadAheadBufferedStream.java:131)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.ReadAheadBufferedStream.read(ReadAheadBufferedStream.java:104)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:247)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacket(StandardPacketInputStream.java:218)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1525)
    ... 13 more
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "connection" is null
    at com.myapplication.controllers.auth.SignInController.lambda$checkIfAdminExists$5(SignInController.java:70)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

This is what my database connection singleton looks like:

```
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn != null) {
            return conn;
        }
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://mydomain.com:3306/databasename?user=currentusery&password=blahblah");
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

I can't connect to it using DataGrip as well. However, DBeaver and HeidiSQL connect just fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: DBeaver uses JDBC just like DataGrip, so are you using the same driver and the same connection string?

Comment: Exactly the same @MarkRotteveel